# Extract artifact details from a gradle project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jenkins, build.gradle

Without publishing the artifacts to the remote repository, how can we extract the groupid, artifact name with extension (and repository if possible) in gradle. I could do something similar with mvn help for the maven projects but need to do the same for gradle ones.
There is a root project (ie. a build.gradle file at the root level and then multiple folders containing actual source code and their corresponding build.gradle files.

Comment: What do you do with Maven?

Comment: Hi Aled - For maven I run -  mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate \
-Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout

Comment: If you are able to modify the `build.gradle`, you can simply add a custom task such as... `tasks.register('version') { println version }`.  Then, simply run `./gradlew version` and parse the output.